# Resize an image to stay within the viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

How can I make an image resize and maintain aspect ratio to stay within the container if the image is larger than the container, but not resize if the image is smaller than the container.

If the width of the image is larger than the width of the container then the following code should apply.

```css
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

If the width of the image is smaller than the width of the container then the following code should apply.

```css
img {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I tried using the following code, but some strange things happen when the image width is larger then the container's width.

```js
img_w = parseInt($("#img").css("width"));
screen_w = parseInt($(window).width());

img_w = parseInt($("#img").css("width"));
screen_w = parseInt($(window).width());

if (img_w > screen_w) {
    $("#img").css("width", screen_w + "px"); // like 100%;
    $("#img").css("height", "auto");
} else {
    $("#img").css("width", "auto");
    $("#img").css("height", "100%");
}
```

Comment: Do you want to retain aspect ratio?

Comment: @steveax Yes, this is what I would like.

Comment: What about using `width:100vw` and `height:100vh`? [Reference](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values-3/#viewport-relative-lengths)

Comment: I've edited your question to clarify, simplify and generalize to make it more useful for future viewers. Please let me know if I've deviated from the intent of your question. Also, you could even get rid of the JavaScript section and the JavaScript related tags as they are no longer relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved with the following CSS:

```
img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: you should put the original code in the question since you now have your solution in the link you provided. Future users will not see what problem you solved with this.

Comment: But nice clean solution btw

Comment: either way there is no more problem visible when you click that link in the question, I know I just was that user

Comment: Good solution, but this could use a better explanation, and possible a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/49440qdc/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and you can see here the result: http://jsfiddle.net/g6rL3L5h/
I think it's now ok and working.

I just delete 'html' in your css.

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

do you needed this?